# ec2 instances and AWS auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-auto-scaling

I use the module, https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance to provision the ec2 instances on AWS. I would like to have AWS auto scaling group feature implemented, i.e. in case one of the ec2 instances is not healthy, AWS auto replaces it. But, I do not see the code, resource "aws_autoscaling_group" inside the above ec2 instance module.
Question:

1. Is it reasonable to implement AWS auto scaling group with the ec2 module? I understand we can implement AWS auto scaling group with eks. But, I am not sure about ec2 instances.
2. If it is possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it is not only reasonable, but actually considered a best practice to use an auto scaling group for EC2 instances.
2. you can do so using the terraform autoscaling module: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/autoscaling/aws/latest

Comment: There is no output of private IP of EC2 instances. It looks like I can only use user data to install stuffs I need at EC2 instance provision time. I cannot use the ASG ec2 instances as my application server since I deploy new releases from time to time. It means I have to logon to the instance via IP, user data does not work.